# Show that the set is Jordan measurable, and find the appropriate Jordan measure (volume).

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $$V=(x,y,z)|(x^2+y^2)^2\leq2(x^2-y^2); x^2+y^2\leq1; z=x^2+y^2;z^2=2(x^2+y^2)\}.$$
Show that the set is Jordan measurable, and find the appropriate Jordan measure (volume).
I was thinking that the set might be compact, and generating a continuous function from (x,y,z) to this set would satisfy Lipsitz condition, and thereby making the set Jordan measurable..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set in question is (0,0,0). Then it is quite obvious.