# Question on extremums, can anyone provide some help?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

The real question: Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$;  $f(x,y_1,y_2)=x^3−xy_1y_2+y_2^2−16$. Show that there exists a differentiable real function $g$ so that in some neighboorhood $(1,4)$ $$f(g(y_1,y_2),y_1,y_2)=0 $$Find $g′(1,4)$ and ${\partial^2g\over \partial x^2}(1,4).$
My theorem of implicit function is:$$$$
$$\large {Implicit\ Theorem:}$$
$$\begin {cases} a.)X,Y,Z ;Banach- spaces, W\subset X \times Y. \\
                 b.)F:W \to Z; F\in C^1; F(a,b)=0.\\
                 c.)D_yF(a,b):Y\to Z -isomorphism-Y-and-Z \end {cases}$$
$Conclusions:$
$$There\ exists\ an \ open\ neighboorhood\ U(a)\in X,\ an \ open \ neighboor\  W'=W'(a,b)\subset W\subset X \times Y and\ a\ function\ f:U\to Y, that: $$
$$\begin {cases} 1.)(x,y)\in W';F(x,y)=0 \iff x\in U ;y=f(x);f(a)=b.\\
                 2.)f\in C^1;f'(a)=-D_yF^{-1}\circ D_xF. \\
                 3.)If\ F \in C^k \implies f\in C^k,(k\geq1).  \end {cases}$$

Comment: Sort your variables and check the implicit function theorem. **Edit:** And what do you mean with $g'$?

Comment: Honestly this is the question write off the page. I assume the first derivative of a function that would satisfy the problem in question.

Comment: Check the notes, the notation must have been defined somewhere. What do you mean derivative of a bi-variable function? Is it the differential (A.K.A. Jacobian) which in this case is the gradient? Still: implicit function theorem.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely the Jacobian, i just can't seem to put it all together, or have a precise outline of what to do. If I were to put a bounty on it of 50 rep, could you type it out in 2 days time? The same applies to this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180659/show-that-the-set-is-jordan-measurable-and-find-the-appropriate-jordan-measure

Comment: I don't care about reputation. A much stronger incentive for me to help is you posting the version of the implicit function theorem you're working with and then your efforts in trying to use the theorem.

Comment: Ill give it a try later on today, keep track ! :)

Comment: I solved a few of this kind of questions in the past, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:55235+[implicit-function-theorem]). Maybe it helps.

Comment: @Git Gud Check out my post when you the the chance.

Comment: In the notation of the theorem, take $X=Z=\mathbb R, Y=\mathbb R^2, F=f, a=0, b=(1,4)$. Also note that $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3\color{grey}{=\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\times \mathbb R}$ are being used interchangeably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are in fact three different such functions $g$.

Preliminary remark: The letters $X$ and $Y$ in your formulation of the implicit function theorem do not correspond to the names $x$,  $y_1$, $y_2$ of the variables in your example!

We are given the function
$$f(x,y,z):=x^3-xyz+z^2-16$$
and are interested in the "surface"  $S: \>f(x,y,z)=0$ in ${\Bbb R}^3$. To be exact, we are also given the point $P:=(1,4)$ in the $(y,z)$-plane, and are asked to present a suitable part of $S$ as a graph
$$x=g(y,z)\qquad\bigl((y,z)\in U\bigr)\tag{1}$$
with $g$ defined in some neighborhood $U$ of $P$. In order to find points of $S$ projecting to $P$ we have to solve the equation
$$\phi(x):=f(x,1,4)=x^3-4x=0$$
for $x$. It follows that $x\in\{-2,0,2\}$, which means that three different points of $S$ project to $P$. In the following we consider the point $(2,1,4)\in S$; the other two can be handled analogously.

Since $f_x(2,1,4)=\phi'(2)=4\ne0$  the implicit function theorem guarantees the following: There is an open box $W:=V\times U\subset{\Bbb R}\times{\Bbb R}^2$ with center $(2,1,4)$ (a "window") such that $S\cap W$ has a representation of the form $(1)$ with a $g\in C^1(U,V)$ and $g(1,4)=2$. This implies 
$$f\bigl(g(y,z),y,z\bigr)\equiv0\qquad\bigl((y,z)\in U\bigr)\ .\tag{2}$$
We now take in $(2)$ the partial derivative with respect to $y$. Using the chain rule we obtain
$$f_x\bigl(g(y,z),y,z\bigr)g_y(y,z)+f_y\bigl(g(y,z),y,z\bigr)\cdot 1\equiv0\ ,$$
and putting $(y,z):=(1,4)$ we obtain
$$f_x(2,1,4)g_y(1,4)+f_y(2,1,4)=0\ ,$$
so that
$$g_y(1,4)=-{f_y(2,1,4)\over f_x(2,1,4)}=-{-8\over 4}=2\ .$$
In a similar way, taking the partial derivative with respect to $z$,  we obtain from $(2)$ the identity
$$f_x\bigl(g(y,z),y,z\bigr)g_z(y,z)+f_z\bigl(g(y,z),y,z\bigr)\cdot 1\equiv0\ ,$$
which for $(y,z):=(1,4)$ gives
$$g_z(1,4)=-{f_z(2,1,4)\over f_x(2,1,4)}=-{6\over4}=-{3\over2}\ .$$
What you call $g'(1,4)$ therefore can be written as
$$dg(1,4).(Y,Z)=2Y-{3\over2}Z\ .$$
The expression ${\partial^2 g\over \partial x^2}(1,4)$ in your question does not make sense..

Answer (score 0):

I'll change the notations for better comprehension.
$$F(y_1,y_2,x)=x^3−xy_1y_2+y_2^2−16$$
$a=(1,4)=(y_1,y_2)\in X=R^2 ; b=0=x\in Y=R;Z=R$ (Z and Y must be the same dimensions..because of isomorphism condition in theorem)Condition $1.\ and\ 2.$ is satisfied obviously because real spaces are Banach spaces and the partial derivatives of $F$ also $\in C^1$ and $F(a,b)=0$. So that means (by the theorem) there exists $g(a)=b; g\in C^1$ such that :$g'(a)=-(D_yF(a,b))^{-1}\circ D_xF(a,b)=...-{4}$